# Using span::before, can a span within a paragraph be vertically positioned within that paragraph?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, pseudo-element

Is there a way to vertically align a span, declared within a paragraph, and align the top of the span with the top of the paragraph?

```
<p> lots of text <span data-pullquote="special text">special text</span></p>
```

better fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/HeavyThumper/e4e01p0h/

Is this possible without altering the paragraph styles - or requiring another container?

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

As far as CSS goes, there are ways to move the pullquotes to the top of the paragraph, unfortunately, properties like `position`, `transform:translate`, etc. takes the pullquote out of the flow thereby disabling the `float` property. The result is the pullquote moved at the top, but also mixed into the text instead of the text flowing around it. `padding-bottom` doesn't work because it disrupts the text below the pullquote. The only solution that I can think of that'll require the least preparation and work is using JavaScript.

Add the following to the end of your JavaScript:

```
var pq = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-pullquote]');
var pqArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(pq);
for (var i = 0; i < pqArray.length; i++) {
  var para = pqArray[i].parentElement;
  var pqHTML = pqArray[i].outerHTML;
  para.removeChild(pqArray[i]);
  para.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', pqHTML);
}
```

Here's a working demo:

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/pfr58exu/)

---

### OLD

Does it look like this? https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/rzeqo7qz/
I moved the `<span>` to the top and made it a `<q>` for semantics, but a `<blockquote>` would probably be better.

Comment: That's the way I want it to look - but by using some form of delimeter (at the moment it's <span>) on the text within the paragraph - without requiring me to add extra text at the start. The application for this is html generated by Pelican, using a pullquote plugin, from Markdown source. So I want to be able to simply type my source text, delimit the phrase for the pullquote, and let the magic happen. It works fine now - but the text is vertically positioned inline with where it is declared. I want to change the vertical position - without having to type the text separately.

Comment: I can change the html delimeter used by the plugin easily - so if <span> needs to be replaced by something else that's not a problem. But moving the text line elsewhere, without requiring me to duplicate it in the source, would be a lot more challenging.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is to use a little JavaScript to move pullquotes to the top of the paragraph once they have been generated. If you use `position` properties, it would no longer have the float property functioning and text wouldn't reflow around the pullquote, same thing with `transform: translate`. `padding-bottom` doesn't work because it disrupts the text.